# Text elipisis in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, cell, nstableview

I have a NSTableView where I would like to have text elipsis in cells. Do you know how I have to proceed?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

AP

Answer (score 0):

In the datasource method objectValueForTableColumn you need to create a NSAttributedString with your desired text format and return it.

Create a paragraph style and set its line break mode.
[pStyle setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail]
Then set the paragraph style as an attribute to the attributed string.

Comment: …except that `NSTableView` is a Mac class and `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` is not available. `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` is probably more appropriate!